# Build opencv application for ARM on x86

Tags: linux, opencv, build, arm, raspberry-pi

I have  problem with building aplication with opencv library for ARM.
I installed Opencv 2.4.6.1  for my pc with helping this a tutorial http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#linux-installation

After that i try build example for my pc:

```
gcc main.c -o main ´pkg-config --libs --clags opencv´ -lpthread
```

It works.

Next, i install arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc, wrote example and tryied it. It works.

now i make opencv library for ARM

```
cd /opt/opencv-2.4.6.1/platforms/linux
mkdir build_hardfp
pico arm-gnueabi.toolchain.cmake

change 4.6 to 4.7.2
cd build_hardfp

cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../arm-gnueabi.toolchain.cmake -DWITH_TBB=OFF -DWITH_QT=OFF -D SOFTFP=OFF -D WITH_V4L=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON  –D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE –D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/opencv-2.4.6.1/rpi ../../..
make
make install
```

And now my problem:

I try build my example

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -o main main.c -lpthread  -I/opt/opencv-2.4.6.1/rpi/include -I/opt/opencv-2.4.6.1/rpi/include/opencv  -I/opt/opencv-2.4.6.1/rpi/lib -L/opt/opencv-2.4.6.1/rpi/ -lcv  -lhighgui
```

main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:12:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/home/honza/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.7.2/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lcv
/home/honza/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.7.2/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lhighgui
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Probably i must have all the dependencies compile for ARM architecture. I  think, i took care of this in previous steps, with using cmake. 
Maybe i didn't set paths.

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Should -I/opt/opencv-2.4.6.1/rpi/lib be -L instead?

Answer (score 1):

You use old names for OpenCV libraries : `-lcv -lhighgui`. OpenCV has new structure from 2.0 version. Use this flags : `-lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui`.

Comment: Hi. Thank you, but something other must be wrong. I change -lcv to -lopencv_core and also with -lhighgui to -lopencv_highgui. The problem is still the same.

Comment: Add -L/opt/opencv-2.4.6.1/rpi/lib option (-L not -I).

Comment: I used -L without -I for libraries. I tried enter all path to libopencv_core.so and libopencv_highgui.so instead of -lopencv_core and  -lopencv_highgui. There is new problem: /opt/opencv-2.4.6.1/rpi/lib/libopencv_core.so: could not read symbols: File in wrong format. I probably to compile OpenCV in corect form for Raspberry Pi.